# validating typed literals in RDF

Tags: json, rdf, jena

given this RDF:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>.
@prefix ex: <http://example.com/>.
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>.

ex:bob ex:has '{"name": robert"}'^^rdf:JSON .
ex:bob ex:at "204453"^^xsd:dateTime .
```

an RDF engine (such as Apache Jena) can validate some of the typed literals (e.g. xsd:dateTime):

```
$ ~/Downloads/apache-jena-4.7.0/bin/riot --validate file.ttl 
11:48:47 WARN  riot            :: [line: 6, col: 14] Lexical form '204453' not valid for datatype XSD dateTime
```

will any RDF engines validate the `rdf:JSON` typed literal?

notice the json isn't well-formed.

Comment: `rdf:JSON` is not a standard RDF datatype which means standard tools most likely will not validate it unless a developer has added this datatype as an extension.

Comment: rdf:JSON is WIP by the RDF 12. Working Group. There is a proposal - it's different to the definition in JSON-LD 1.1. All open source engines would appreciate contributions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JavaScript SPARQL Functions](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/javascript-functions.html) in ARQ to implement a simple custom function that will tell you if a literal is parsable as JSON.

This Gist demonstrates how that can be done: https://gist.github.com/jaw111/3955e6fb9aa48c7d627cec685a9d5cca

Answer (score 1):

I like John Walker's solution but we also discovered that if you attempt to serialize that RDF (with the malformed json literal) as jsonld using Apache Jena it will validate the json literals:

```
$ apache-jena-4.7.0/bin/riot --formatted=jsonld file.ttl

org.apache.jena.shared.JenaException: Exception while writing JSON-LD 1.1
...
Caused by: JsonLdError[code=An invalid JSON literal was detected [code=INVALID_JSON_LITERAL]., message=An invalid JSON literal was detected [code=INVALID_JSON_LITERAL].]
```